# ROS1 Noetic Slam Toolbox No Map received in rviz

Tags: slam, ros-noetic

i want to use the slam toolbox to create a map.
I git cloned the slam_toolbox package inside my workspace and created a slam_toolbox.launch file. However, the map doesn't show up. Did i forget something ?

I using ros1 noetic.

I using the neuronbot2 robot available on github(noetic branch).

Thank you so much for any help !

1.This is a info from the terminal. How can i fix that?:

https://ibb.co/LxFMdcS

2.Here is my slam_toolbox launch file:

https://ibb.co/DWnrBGW

3.This is how rviz look like. Unfortuneately no map received:

https://ibb.co/WvPHrth

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code and terminal output as formatted text, you can use this [formatting guide](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) and this [question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/robotics-stack-exchange-question-checklist) to improve your question.